# Truncating Text with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got this html layout and I'm trying to truncate text when scaling down the window. And I'm using bootstrap for it. I've also added the css part for hiding overflown text.

But I get something like that instead: [image]

```
.evLabel.form-control {
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

    <div style="clear:both;" class="firstFormDiv col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <label class="lbl-no-padding col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="margin-top:5px">
        Label
        </label>
        <div class="f_lookup_191361 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="ev-input-group input-group" style="width:100%;">
                <span class="evLabel form-control col-sm-12 col-xs-12 " title="Some Title">Long Text That Needs to be Truncated</span>
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" style="float:right;" class="btn inp-button edit_button" data-reditcontroller="/someUrl" true="">
                        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                    </button>
                </span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you share working fiddle for this

Comment: I'm afraid not, the code generates dynamically from database, so that would be complicated to get the whole layout as a working thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just change the tag from `<span>` to `<input/>` and made it `readonly`. Worked for me. Apperently bootstrap doesn't go along with `<span>` so well. At least in my case.

Comment: truncate text doesn't seem to work with span's nor labels either

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Use meta viewport in `<head> </head>`.

Answer (score 0):

When your text exceeds certain width (limit) then apply the text-overflow: ellipsis

Example:

```
 .txt-overflow-ellipsis {
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    white-space: pre; /* or nowrap*/
    }

    <p class="txt-overflow-ellipsis">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>
```